# tableview cells not updating properly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using table view to show downloaded songs.I am creating empty folder before downloading song without extinction ".mp3" after downloading song I am replacing that file with original file which has extinction of .mp3 .now aim getting files on music folder and shooing it in table view. The table view shows activity indicator in cell before downloading song. After downloading song i replace the activity indicator by a button by hiding it. My problem is after downloading the file it was not able to replace the button but it hid the indicator. even though i scrolled the button doesn't appear. Whenever i close that view controller and return back to download list it shows properly. after downloading file i tried `[tableview reload data];` but no change.

any help would be appreciated
              iam usingI am using table view to show downloaded songs. The table view shows activity indicator in cell before downloading song. After downloading song i replace the activity indicator by a button by hiding it. My problem is after downloading the file it was not able to replace the button but it hid the indicator. even though i scrolled the button doesn't appear. Whenever i close that view controller and return back to download list it shows properly. after downloading file i tried `[tableview reload data];` but no change.

any help would be appreciated

```
                             if((![[songName substringFromIndex:MAX((int)            [songName length]-4, 0)] isEqualToString:@".mp3"])    
       {        
CoustoumCell *cellMain = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];           
    cellMain.backgroundView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Table-view-background.png"]];           
 cellMain.AlbumLable.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.278 green:0.278  blue:0.278 alpha:1.0];
cellMain.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Table-view-selected-background.png"]];
cellMain.indiCatorForDon.tag=indexPath.row;
[cellMain.indiCatorForDon startAnimating];
[cellMain.playButton removeFromSuperview];

cellMain.imageView.image=Nil;
cellMain.downloadStatusLable.text=@"Downloading....";
cellMain.AlbumLable.text=[_songsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cellMain.numberLable.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row+1];
}
   else
{
CoustoumCell *cellMain = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cellMain.backgroundView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Table-view-background.png"]];
cellMain.AlbumLable.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.278 green:0.278    blue:0.278 alpha:1.0];
cellMain.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Table-view-selected-background.png"]];
cellMain.AlbumLable.text=[_songsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cellMain.indiCatorForDon stopAnimating];
cellMain.downloadStatusLable.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.278 green:0.278 blue:0.278 alpha:1.0];
cellMain.sizeLable.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.278 green:0.278 blue:0.278 alpha:1.0];
cellMain.sizeLable.text=[[self getSize] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cellMain.downloadStatusLable.text=@"Downloaded";
cellMain.completedImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
    cellMain.numberLable.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row+1];
cellMain.playButton.tag=indexPath.row;
}
    return cellMain;
```

after downloading song sending notification from another view to table view

```
  - (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
   if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"])
         {
           NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");

    // Perform long running process
       [self  updateDownloadList];
       [[AlbumsAnsSongs sharedManager] getallFiles];
       [_tableView reloadData];
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: Are you using reusable cells?

Comment: yah,  I am using

Comment: @user1000 Now i update it with code.

Comment: @VenkateshSRoyal Please show the code where you are calling [tableView reloadData]; and please check the answer

Comment: @user1000 Now i Update that code also please solve it

Comment: Please check the answer and replace [_tableView reloadData] with the answer

Comment: @user1000 no change user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since problem is with UI update so I guess when your data completes downloading you should call reloadData method like this:

```
 - (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
   if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"])
         {
           NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");

    // Perform long running process
       [self  updateDownloadList];
       [[AlbumsAnsSongs sharedManager] getallFiles];

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [_tableView reloadData];
        });

   }
 }
```

Another problem that seems to be there is that you are removing the button with this statement

```
[cellMain.playButton removeFromSuperview];
```

but in else part you are not adding the button back,

I think instead of removing playButton you should hide the button

```
cellMain.playButton.hidden = YES
```

and then in else part

```
cellMain.playButton.hidden = NO
```

**Explanation:**

You were removing the button from cell, since the cells are dequed or you can say reused , cells without button were being displayed on the screen

Comment: I am downloading file in Web View After receiving response i am moving to downloading list after downloading file i am sending notification  to download list view and  get whole list of songs and  done reload data.

Comment: @VenkateshSRoyal I updated the answer please replace your function with this and tell me what is the output?

Comment: super bro,Its working Thank You  but shall i know the reason

Comment: Good work, I added a little explanation in the answer, please check if you do not understand and tell me